# Why Postfix more secure than Sendmail?

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I saw a lot of (old) articles that mentioned

- Sendmail has weak security architecture
- Postfix is much more secure than Sendmail
  But those articles did not explain why.

I think, in the past, there are CVEs of Sendmail more than Postfix. But what about today? Any reason to not use the Sendmail?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail is based on ancient design from pre spam era (times of "small" friendly internet). Sedmail **had been** installed by default as "set root id" program [fixed in sendmail-12].  It had provided easy escalation path for security problems.

Postfix has been designed later with more dangerous internet in mind.

Sendmail is incredibly configurable but it gets a lot of effort/learning to access its **full** capabilities.  AFAIK there will be no sendmail-9 [see [MeTA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeTA1)].
My personal sendmail suggestion for up to medium level postmasters is "KEEP (if you are medium+ user)".  Advanced postmasters are usually far beyond point of "easy change".